# JSON Array Problem

Tags: java, android, json

Hy!

I have a JSON Array with the tv channels and the lenght of the array is three, but after transmitting into a treemap the Value is only one.

Please Help

Code:

```
try
            {

                JSONObject menuobj = this.getJSONObject("responseData");
                Log.e("XXX", menuobj.toString());
                JSONArray array = menuobj.getJSONArray("countries");
                TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                    obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (obj.getString("name").equals(country))
                    {
                        Log.e("XXX2", obj.toString());
                        JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("channels");
                        Log.e("XXX3", String.valueOf(arr.length()));
                        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length(); j++)
                        {
                            JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
                            obj2 = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                            map.put(obj2.getString("name"), obj2.getInt("id"));
                        }
                        Log.e("XXX4", String.valueOf(map.size()));
                        return map;
                    }


                }
```

LogCat:

```
02-01 18:24:20.277: ERROR/XXX(3784): {"countries":[{"id":"1","channels":[{"id":"3","name":"ARD"},{"id":"1","name":"ORF 1"},{"id":"2","name":"ORF 2"}],"name":"Ã?sterreich"},{"id":"2","channels":[{"id":"3","name":"ARD"}],"name":"Deutschland"}]}
02-01 18:24:20.288: ERROR/XXX2(3784): {"id":"1","channels":[{"id":"3","name":"ARD"},{"id":"1","name":"ORF 1"},{"id":"2","name":"ORF 2"}],"name":"Ã?sterreich"}
02-01 18:24:20.297: ERROR/XXX3(3784): 3
02-01 18:24:20.307: ERROR/XXX4(3784): 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe :

```
obj2 = arr.getJSONObject(i);
```

should be

```
obj2 = arr.getJSONObject(j);
```

So you are putting three times the same object pair of key/value to the map.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JSONArray` without `JSONObject`:

```
 JSONArray resultJson = new JSONArray(responseDataString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an important logging detail, call it `XXX3.5`.  It's almost certainly the case that the map contains one element because each call to `map.put()` is passing in a key that is considered equal to the key already inside the map.

Now I'd expect these keys to be the String names of the channels, which are distinct, so clearly this expectation isn't holding.  Adding a log message of `obj2.getString("name")` (or alternatively setting a breakpoint there), will let you see what the map keys actually are, and why subsequent calls are overwriting the existing mapping.  Outputting the actual class of the object would be useful too, in order to distinguish between an actual `String` and some class that merely contains a String.

If the elements look sensible, the problem could be a loose definition of `equals()` on the class in question, which equates elements that ought to seem distinct.  In any case, better logging will show why

```
arr.getJSONObject(0).getString("name").equals(arr.getJSONObject(1).getString("name")
```

returns true when you expect this to return false.

Comment: ^^ three time ARD 02-01 18:38:46.627: ERROR/XXX3.5(4148): ARD
02-01 18:38:46.627: ERROR/XXX3.5(4148): ARD
02-01 18:38:46.627: ERROR/XXX3.5(4148): ARD